# Displaying animated SVG in JavaFX on different computers fails

Tags: java, svg, javafx

I'm currently working on a JavaFX program with some fellow students. 
We organized everything with GIT - thus, our SVG-files look alike. 
We are also doing some animation within our SVG.

The problem is, that when my friends start their NetBeans, the SVG is not displayed correctly. Some parts are missing out. When they open the SVG with their web-browser however - it works. 
Here's the part that is missing out on my friends PC.

```
  <polyline id="beampath"  stroke="brown" stroke-width="4" fill="transparent">
   <animate id="bridgeLeft" attributeName="points" dur="1s" 
   begin = "0s; bridgeLeft.end + 2.5s "
    from="20,62 30,62 35,62  50,62 "
      to="20,62 30,62 35,70  45,88"
      fill = "freeze"
    />
   </polyline>
```

Does someone have any clue why that's the case?
We're really desperate.

Comment: Removed the tag. :)